# How to create Youtube style Android ListView populated with video, buttons, textview per list?

Tags: android, listview

I have a new project, I want to create a list view same in youtube
like list populated with the ff.

1. with video clickable, if click launch to new activity that play the video
2. with text title of the video with time duration how long the video is.
3. last is the button with has function of download the video or play it if already have

something like that,
I have [created a screenshot](http://prntscr.com/1rkce9) of my target style

Comment: you need use a custom listview by inflating a  custom layout for each row in listview

Comment: @adasdasdas : Please make use of Google. Search for creating custom views in android and you would get plenty of hits.

Comment: can you give me a good links for it for custom listview in inflating custom layout? thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

use custom listview and inflate your custom view.
see [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)
, [this](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/) and [this](http://javatechig.com/android/android-listview-tutorial/) example.

Comment: rachit thank you so much for this links, i learn from it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a custom [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html), in which you will build list entries of the data from some source. You can create a custom layout for the entries, where you can add virtually anything you want.